# Pass value via URL to ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, url

I am trying to pass a value to a box on an ASPX page. How can this be done? For example, the following page.

http://irth.digsafelynewyork.com/IRTHOneCall/Ticket/PositiveResponse/PositiveResponse.aspx?ID=

It appears as though it will allow passing the ticket id at the end of the URL, however it will not work.

Comment: You are developing that aspx page or you are trying to retrieve data from it?  If it's case two, which part didn't work as you expect?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve data from it. I have a mapping application that has the ticket id in it already. I would like to pass the ticket ID in the URL. For instance the URL above will not work if you put the ticket ID after "ID=". You have to put the ticket ID in the ticket id box on the page for it to work. So the question is, how do I pass the ticket ID in the URL to get a result. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is passing a value using the query string. Like in your URL, you are passing a value using query string parameter "ID".

In yoru aspx page, you can read this value using Request object and then assign this value to textbox.

```
string ticketId = Request.QueryString["ID"].ToString();
Textbox1.Text = ticketId;
```